# Fine Bluetooth Volume Control

Tags: bluetooth, volume, speaker

I connect my Pixel 3 to JBL Flip 4 via bluetooth. The volume rocker buttons don't increment the volume in equal installments, which is very noticeable at the lower volume range. I installed the Precise Volume app to get the actual numbers and it looks like the bump from 12% to 13% is barely noticeable (which is how it should be) whereas from 13% to 14% is quite significant (which is annoying, hence this post)

If I use the Flip 4 via an aux cable this isn't an issue as the two volume controls become decoupled - the speaker's volume buttons affect the speaker's volume without affecting the phone volume, and you can get much finer control over the volume with small, equal increments (leave phone on 5-10% and play with the speaker's volume until it sounds good)

Basically, I am interested in being able to make fine adjustments to the volume coming from a bluetooth speaker, but it looks like it's just a bluetooth limitation that I can do nothing about.

Can anybody comment on with any thoughts or workaround ideas (other than using aux)?

ps: the actual use case i am after is that i like listening to audiobooks at night, don't want to deal with a cable in bed, really want to find a fully wireless solution where I can set the volume exactly right, but I kind of feel blocked by the technology and don't see a way around it

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:
To decouple phone volume and speaker volume enable what's now called `Disable absolute volume` in developer options (looks like used to be called `Disable max volume`)

[Taken from here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bluetooth-volume-steps-too-big.3578370/)

Comment: Well, I found that option but it did no difference at all. I have a charge 5 and a moto x4 btw. Is there any extra step that I have to follow?

Comment: This made all the difference in my case, very loud at the low end. Brilliant.

Comment: @user349394 try to unpair and pair again device.